# Vue-Google-Charts title, x and y axis, and ChartOptions() method not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The chartOptions() doesn't seem to work nor display the title/subtitle. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm not sure why the labels for the graph aren't displaying. I am using Vue.

```
<template>
<div id="app" style="width: 60%">
          <h2 style="padding-center: 50px">Temperature</h2>
          <GChart
            type="AreaChart"
            :data="chartData"
            :options="chartOptions"
          />
        </div>
</template>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    GChart, 
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          title: "Temperature",
          subtitle: "By Hour",
          colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
        },

}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add <script> which is placed after the end of </template>

Comment: vue2 not 3, correct?

Comment: yes I believe so